# js-widgets not working after installation of nbextensions

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

[jupyter notebook nbextension tab screen snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHVVC.png)

I have installed jupyter nbextensions configurator and jupyter contrib nbextensions and the js-widgets extension no longer functions correctly in my code. I haven't activated any extensions, how would I be able to make js-widgets work again?

I tried pip uninstalling both of these pakages, and js-widgets still didn't work correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated in order to get js-widgets to work again.

Thanks.